# Weird Boot on iMac

Tags: imac, install

Help would be really appreciated on this one!
My Dads iMac won't boot.
When it's turned on (running Yosemite) it gets stuck in the boot process and looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvBXK.jpg
There is no mouse pointer showing etc, just that bar stuck as shown above.
I waited overnight and still it gets no further. I've listened and the disk seems Ok (no weird noises)

In addition to that I've done the following:
* tried to hold alt to bring up boot options (seemingly ignored and apple logo / progress bar come up as shown)

*tried to reset pram (screen went black and rebooted, made no difference)

*tried to boot off to the original OSX discs. (Holding "c", cd spins up but seemingly just spins down and apple logo / progress bar appear as above)

*tried cmd-r for recovery (result as previous, ignored with progress bar / logo showing
tried cmd-v for verbose start up same as previous. Seemingly ignored.

I'm an apple geek so usually pretty good with this stuff but I'm out of ideas. Is this a general hardware failure?

Comment: Did you try to do an internet recovery if the normal recovery doesn't work?

Comment: Have you attempted Safe Mode (hold down shift at boot chime)? This should be first troubleshoot step with boot problems.